# Adjusting height based on depth

Tags: calculus

I'm coding something for a website, however, i'm stuck on a bit of Maths which is involved.

I will try my best to explain the issue. Let's say there are 3 layers, each of which occupies the same area, however, they move at different speeds depending on their "depth", so due to them being further away from the "camera" we need to adjust their size.

container height: 500.
window height: 860.

layer 1 depth: 1.0 (this is basically unchanged, so it's height should remain at 500). 
layer 2 depth: 0.5
layer 3 depth: 0.1

So, let's say that 0.1 means that this layer needs to be 90% the size of the window height, however, the calculation needs to account that 1.0 will simply be the size of the container...

If this doesn't make sense let me know and I will try and find a visual aid.

P.S. I know nothing about Maths apart from the basics so sorry if I used the wrong tags, had NO IDEA what to put there...

Comment: What precisely is the question?

Comment: I need a calculation that will calculate for example 90% of the window height when the depth is 0.1. however a depth of 1.0 should be the height of the container

Comment: I'm confused in whats the main focus here -- the container height or window height. So let me see if I get this right: for simplicity lets let the "window height" be $x_0=500$ and the "container height" be $y_0=860$. I understand a depth of $0\leq d\leq 1$ means the window height at that layer is is $$x=(1-d)x_0$$ where $x$ is the new value of the window height.

Comment: How is the container height, $y_0$, affected by differing depths?